# Good way of communicating between web and desktop app

Tags: c#, java, windows, desktop-application

I want my web app (running in a browser) to, at some point, communicate (bidirectionally) with a desktop app (in Windows), the client has installed in its computer.

What's an elegant and modular and simple way of doing this (with Java and C#)?

Not much information will be passed between the web app and the desktop app. Just something like "I was here", "Pick this from this point", etc.

Comment: Do you want the web app to call the desktop app OR the other way around ?

Comment: see my answer below for some options...

Answer (score 2):

I solved that problem by using a database on the network.
All communications where made trough the database.

Website -> DB -> User logged in <- DB <- Desktop

However, if no trusted information needs to be shared, you could consider just posting and reading some http headers to a common website, or a simple log file.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the backend part of your webapp, assuming that your app is based on some backend services.

You have two options:

1. Your desktop apps use the same services of your web app. You must use a class that mimic a web-browser to give the data ([curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), ie). If your web app is based on AJAX push ( [APE Server](http://www.ape-project.org/) i.e ) use library that is able to run some javascript
2. Use a REST protocol, with a JSON format in your backend services. It's easy to manage and is supported by many client-side languages (java/c#/python....)
3. Use a specialized endpoint only for your desktop app,for C#, you can use WCF, that    allow you, in one of his forms bidirectional communications. For JAVA, there are WSDL, DWR

My preferred solution is to decouple the web app in a front-end side and a backend side, that expose the services as REST that are used by the web app via AJAX.

If I need true bidirectional communication with other desktop app, I'll create a separate service / endpoint for it. (APE , WCF, ..)

Answer (score 1):

I see several options to achieve part of what you are asking:

Besically you expose the relevant parts of your apps (web and desktop) via some sort of API and use that for the communication - for example DB and/or WCF (SOAP/REST/whatever).

BEWARE:

If you are after some sort of direct/interactive communication between both apps on the same computer then this won't be possible - at least not without some security related issues.

The browser executes your web app in a sandbox which doesn't allow for direct communication between the web app and the desktop... there are technologies which can help circumvent that (ActiveX, signed Java applets, some Flash technology called AIR etc.)... or you could host some webbrowser/control in your desktop app which in turn runs the web app... BUT basically I would recommend against using any such measures...

IF you really want to go this route then please describe your environment and goal with much more detail.